# Unreal Engine 5.2 - Trying to build my plugin on UE 5.2 but the error cannot be referenced – it is a deleted function is showing up

Tags: c++, build, unreal-engine5

I’m trying to build my plugin on UE 5.2, but the following error is showing up:

> C++ function (declared at line xx of) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function

The problem is in the use of the UBlackboardComponent, I’m defining it like this:

```
BBComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<UBlackboardComponent>(TEXT("BlackBoardComp"));
UBlackboardData* const bbData = BehaviorTree->BlackboardAsset;
BBComponent->InitializeBlackboard(*bbData);
```

Then, when I try to get a key from the UBlackboardComponent:

```
targetActorKey = BBComponent->GetKeyID("TargetActor");
```

I’m getting this error:

> C++ function (declared at line xx of) cannot be referenced – it is a deleted function

I don’t know if I can share UE code, assuming it is open source, I will share the code of the FBlackboard:

```
// Copyright Epic Games, Inc. All Rights Reserved.

#pragma once

#include "UObject/NameTypes.h"

namespace FBlackboard
{
    const FName KeySelf = TEXT("SelfActor");

#ifdef AI_BLACKBOARD_KEY_SIZE_8
    // this is the legacy BB key size. Add AI_BLACKBOARD_KEY_SIZE_8 to your *.target.cs to enable it.
    using FKey = uint8;
    inline constexpr FKey InvalidKey = FKey(-1);
#else
    //the default BB key size is now 16
    struct FKey
    {
        constexpr FKey() = default;
        FKey(int32 InKey) {Key = IntCastChecked<uint16>(InKey); }
        constexpr FKey(uint16 InKey) : Key(InKey) {}
        constexpr FKey(uint8 InKey) = delete;
        constexpr operator int32() const { return Key; }
        constexpr operator uint16() const { return Key; }
        constexpr operator uint8() const = delete;
        constexpr bool operator==(const FKey& Other) const {return Key == Other.Key;}
        constexpr bool operator!=(const FKey& Other) const {return Key != Other.Key;}
    private:
        friend uint32 GetTypeHash(const FKey& Key);
        uint16 Key = static_cast<uint16>(-1);
    };

    inline constexpr FKey InvalidKey = FKey();

    inline uint32 GetTypeHash(const FKey& Key) { return ::GetTypeHash(Key.Key);}
#endif
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Many thanks!

I've tried to change the call:

```
targetActorKey = BBComponent->GetKeyID("TargetActor");
```

To

```
uint16 targetActorKey = BBComponent->GetKeyID("TargetActor");
```

But this didnt worked.

Answer (score 0):

Change the return value to uint16 works for me.